# Writing my own jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas

I am trying to write a jQuery Plugin from a piece of JS code I had written.  What this plugin does is it converts a select box into a map of Australia where I can select individual states. It's working perfectly well. However, I'd like to know how I can write it with OOP principles like SOLID etc. can someone review my code and suggest changes.

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

// undefined is used here as the undefined global variable in ECMAScript 3 is
// mutable (ie. it can be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really being
// passed in so we can ensure the value of it is truly undefined. In ES5, undefined
// can no longer be modified.

// window and document are passed through as local variable rather than global
// as this (slightly) quickens the resolution process and can be more efficiently
// minified (especially when both are regularly referenced in your plugin).

// Create the defaults once
var pluginName = "genAusMap",
    defaults = {};

// The actual plugin constructor
function Plugin ( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    var imagesLoaded = 0;
    var canvas, ctx,ausMap,states;
    var elemLeft,elemTop;

    this.setCanvas = function(c,w,h){
        canvas = c;
        canvas.setAttribute('width',w);
        canvas.setAttribute('height',h);
        // Add event listener for `click` events.
        $(canvas).on('click', function(event) {
            var x = event.pageX - elemLeft, y = event.pageY - elemTop;
            canvas.width = canvas.width; // clear the canvas
            ctx.drawImage(ausMap, 0, 0);
            if (y > 59 && y < 164 && x > 146 && x < 205) {
                drawImageOnLoad('nt');
            }
            if (y > 59 && y < 192 && x > 205 && x < 301) {
                drawImageOnLoad('qld');
            }
            if (y > 164 && y < 249 && x > 147 && x < 214) {
                drawImageOnLoad('sa');
            }
            if (y > 260 && y < 295 && x > 229 && x < 261) {
                drawImageOnLoad('tas');
            }
            if (y > 223 && y < 260 && x > 213 && x < 265) {
                drawImageOnLoad('vic');
            }
            if ((y > 191 && y < 222 && x > 220 && x < 297) || (y > 221 & y < 233 & x > 230  & x < 277) || (y > 233 & y < 245 & x > 254  & x < 269) ) {
                // ctx.rect(220,191,77,31); ctx.rect(230,221,47,12); ctx.rect(254,233,15,12); ctx.stroke();       // draw a rectangle box with the various co-ordinates to know where to start from and where to end for nsw /
                drawImageOnLoad('nsw');
            }
            if ((y > 207 && y < 232 && x > 240 && x < 270) || (y > 233 & y < 245 & x > 254  & x < 269)) {
                // ctx.rect(240,207,30,25); ctx.rect(254,233,15,12); ctx.stroke();
                drawImageOnLoad('act');
            }
            if (y > 75 && y < 235 && x > 40 && x < 146) {
                drawImageOnLoad('wa');
            }
        });
    };

    this.setCanvasOffsets = function(l,t){
        elemLeft = l;
        elemTop = t;
    };

    this.getCanvas = function(){
        return canvas;
    };
    this.setCtx = function(c){
        ctx = c;
    };
    this.getCtx = function(){
        return ctx;
    };
    this.setAusMap = function(map){
        ausMap = map;
    }
    this.setStates = function(listOfStates){
        states = listOfStates;
    }
    // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
    // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
    // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
    // future instances of the plugin

    var checkAllImagesLoaded = function () {
        imagesLoaded += 1;
        if(imagesLoaded == 9) {
            drawImageOnLoad();
        }
    };
    var drawImageOnLoad = function(drawState){
        drawState = typeof drawState !== 'undefined' ? drawState : ''; // Assigning Default value
        if(imagesLoaded == 9) {
            canvas.width = canvas.width;
            ctx.drawImage(ausMap, 0, 0);
            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
            $.each(states, function(state){
                state = this;
                console.log(drawState);
                if(drawState == state.getAttribute('data-name')) {
                    ctx.drawImage(state, parseInt(state.getAttribute('data-positionX')), parseInt(state.getAttribute('data-positionY')));
                    //selectDeselectOption(state.getAttribute('data-name'));
                }
            });
        }
    };
    this.imageObj = function(src, x, y,name){
        this.src = src;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.name = name;

    };
    this.loadImage = function(image, onload) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = checkAllImagesLoaded;
        img.src = image.src;
        img.setAttribute('data-positionX',image.x);
        img.setAttribute('data-positionY', image.y);
        img.setAttribute('data-name', image.name);
        return img;
    };
    var selectDeselectOption = function(state){
        $(this.element).val(state);
    };


    if(this.element.tagName == 'SELECT') {
        this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.states = [];
        this.init();
    } else {
        alert('Cannot instantiate plugin '+pluginName+' on a '+this.element.tagName+'. Try using a SELECT element instead');
    }
}

// Avoid Plugin.prototype conflicts
$.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
    init: function () {
        $el = $(this.element);
        this.setCanvas(document.createElement('canvas'),319,313);
        this.setCtx(this.getCanvas().getContext("2d"));
        this.setAusMap(this.loadImage(new this.imageObj(this.settings.mapOfAustralia ,0,0)));
        this.states.push(this.loadImage(new this.imageObj('http://localhost/test/act.png',0,0,'act')));
        this.states.push(this.loadImage(new this.imageObj('http://localhost/test/nsw.png',0,0,'nsw')));
        this.states.push(this.loadImage(new this.imageObj('http://localhost/test/nt.png',0,0,'nt')));
        this.states.push(this.loadImage(new this.imageObj('http://localhost/test/sa.png',0,0,'sa')));
        this.states.push(this.loadImage(new this.imageObj('http://localhost/test/qld.png',0,0,'qld')));
        this.states.push(this.loadImage(new this.imageObj('http://localhost/test/tas.png',0,0,'tas')));
        this.states.push(this.loadImage(new this.imageObj('http://localhost/test/vic.png',0,0,'vic')));
        this.states.push(this.loadImage(new this.imageObj('http://localhost/test/wa.png',0,0,'wa')));
        this.setStates(this.states);
        $el.after(this.getCanvas());
        console.log(this.getCanvas());
        this.setCanvasOffsets(this.getCanvas().offsetLeft,this.getCanvas().offsetTop)
    }
});

// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
// preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
    this.each(function() {
        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
            $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
        }
    });

    // chain jQuery functions
    return this;
};

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin looks like an attempt to reinvent [image maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.6) using a canvas.  Most of this code could be eliminated in favour of techniques that were available in 1997.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It would have definitely become easier if I had used image maps. However, let's just assume I want to use canvas in lieu of image maps. In that case, how can I improve the JS bit of the code? 

Having said that I would definitely consider a rewrite using image maps.